# What do $z_{obs}$ and $t_{obs}$ mean in statistics?

Tags: inference

I am a statistics student who just read a slide where $t_{obs}$ and $z_{obs}$ are mentioned.

After a lot of searching I still cannot find an answer that exactly describe this notation and its meaning clearly.

Can you please help?

Comment: Most likely "obs" stands for "observed". $t$ and $z$ refer to test statistics associated with Student's $t$ and the standard normal distributions respectively.

Comment: @RichardBorder thanks, but what should I as a student do when I see this notation?

Comment: You should look backwards through the document for the first reference, description, or definition of the notation.  If none exists, then you need to infer it from the context.  If you cannot do that, discard the document -- it's unsuitable for you.